# Was a deal needed with Fox to use Evan Peters?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, production, x-men-cinematic-universe, copyright, wandavision

In WandaVision, Evan Peters is cast as a version of Wanda's brother Pietro, aka Peter, aka Quicksilver. The Quicksilver in the X-Men movies is generally considered a different character than Pietro Maximoff in the MCU, though both are versions of the same comic book character. Given that the same actor played Quicksilver in multiple X-Men movies, was the likeness of the character as portrayed by Evan Peters owned by Fox?

Did Marvel Studios need to get a license or permissions from Fox to use that character? Or does using the same actor playing a similar character not fall into using the likeness of that character?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This [article](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment-arts/tv/story/2021-02-05/wandavision-marvel-pietro-maximoff-quicksilver) by the LA Times has a good explanation which can be summed up with

> Disney’s acquisition of Fox in 2019 changed that. Fox’s separate “X-Men” franchise is no more, and Marvel Studios is free to incorporate any of those characters into the MCU.

Comment: I edited the question to replace Sony with Fox; I was just getting mixed up on the Spider-Man thing. Thanks!